# Why is the request ignoring my proxy parameter and returning my IP to me?

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, urllib3

It all started with the fact that I reinstalled paycharm on my computer, reinstalled python
For example, I write normal code, it always worked:

```
import os
import requests
proxies = {'https': 'https://181.232.190.130:999'}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies
r = s.get(url = 'http://wtfismyip.com/text', verify=False)
ip = r.text
print ('Your IP is ' + ip)
os.system("pause")
```

Of course, the proxies are up-to-date and work.
The problem is that the request returns me my real IP. As if it just ignores this parameter.
I am sure that the problem is not in the code, but in something else! But I have no idea where to look! Spent a whole day, but could not achieve anything!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code requests/urllib contains bug i believe.

**Here modified version code:**

Don't use https with your proxy, it will throw version errors. And use proxy for all protocols http/https. Just make changes to these two lines.

> proxy = 'http://198.59.191.234:8080'
> session.proxies = {"http":proxy, "https": proxy}

```
import os
import requests

session = requests.Session()

proxy = 'http://198.59.191.234:8080'
session.proxies ={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}

res = session.get(url = 'http://ipecho.net/plain', verify=False)

print ('Your IP is ' , res.text)
os.system("pause")
```

**Output:**

```
Your IP is  198.59.191.243
Press any key to continue . . .
```